# Redmine - backlogs - No such file to load -- nokogiri

Tags: ruby, redmine, redmine-plugins

I'm trying to install backlogs 0.9.9 with redmine 2.1.2 under ubuntu 12.10.

Following the [Backlogs installation guide](https://github.com/backlogs/redmine_backlogs/wiki/Installation-of-Backlogs-in-Redmine-2.0)

```
remine_install_path$ RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake db:migrate

rake aborted!
No such file to load -- nokogiri
/home/git/redmine/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/acti...
[...]
```

However nokogiri seems to be there

```
$ gem list | grep nokogiri
nokogiri (1.5.5)
```

Am I doing something wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could have simply added

```
gem "nokogiri"
```

into `redmine_install/Gemfile`

**But** `backlogs` (the plugin that I was trying to install) should already contain the dependencies if I had not stupidly removed the backlogs' Gemfile.

I finally simply had to re-checkout the backlogs sources to get my Gemfile back

```
backlogs_plugin_path$ git checkout "latest_version"
```

Replace "latest_version" with the latest version (found with `git tags`)